# How can I check whether an expression was an assignment? (in callback passed to `addTaskCallback`)

Tags: r

how can I check whether an expression was an assignment in a callback passed to `addTaskCallback`? The callback takes four arguments. The first argument passed to the callback is "the S-language expression for the top-level task". The [Top-level Task Callbacks in R](http://developer.r-project.org/TaskHandlers.pdf) manual suggests that you can "examine the expression and determine if any assignments were made". But how can I do that consistently for any assignments in the global environment? I basically want to know if any objects were added or changed in the global environment and only execute my callback if that is the case. It's easy to check for basic assignment operations such as `<-` or `=` but I am not sure about loops (which are one top-level expression), if conditions or functions that use the `<<-` operator or possible other ways to change objects in the global environment. Here are some examples of single top-level operations that include assignments in the global environment

```
# loops
for (i in 1:10) x[i] <- i
for (i in 1:10) {
    x[i] <- i
    y[i] <- i
}
# if conditions
if(cond) x <- rnorm(1000)
if(cond) {
    x <- rnorm(1000)
    y <- rnorm(1000)
}
# global assignment in loop
fn = function() x <<- rnorm(1000)
fn()
```

And finally a very basic example that checks for simple `=` and `<-` operators:

```
eventHandler = function(expr, value, ok, visible) {
    if(class(expr) %in% c('=','<-'))
        print('assignment!')
    # as.character(expr)[2] should now reference the object that was changed
    TRUE
}
addTaskCallback(eventHandler)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to know if objects have been created, modified or deleted, you could have a summary of the previous state of the .GlobalEnv - a named vector, names are objects names and values are hash values (from the `digest` package). The following is working but cost a lot when .GlobalEnv contains big R objects (in the get.hash function).

First a function that is calling digest, its argument is an R object name.

```
get.hash = function( x ){
  require( digest)
  obj = get(x, envir = .GlobalEnv )
  digest( obj, algo = "sha1" )
} # digest call
```

Some objects are not interesting to be monitored

```
# objects to exclude from ls :
obj.exclude = c(".Random.seed")
```

The callback function now. Because *assign* or functions that call *assign* could be used, I don't think scanning 'left assignment' and 'equal' symbols is enough. The names and hash value of objects will be used for tracing objects'signature.

```
.my.callback.fun <- function() {
  old = ls( envir= .GlobalEnv, all.names = TRUE )
  old = setdiff( old, obj.exclude )

  options( "old_desc" = sapply( old, get.hash ) )

  eventHandler <- function(...) {
    # get the previous .GlobalEnv
    old_desc = getOption( "old_desc") # get the previous .GlobalEnv
    old = names( old_desc )

    # list the current .GlobalEnv
    new = ls( envir= .GlobalEnv, all.names = TRUE )
    new = setdiff( new, obj.exclude )
    new_desc = sapply( new, get.hash )

    if (!all( is.element( old,  new ) ) )
      message("deleted objects: "
        , paste( old[!is.element( old, new )], collapse = ", " ) )

    if (!all( is.element( new, old ) ) ) 
      message("new objects: "
        , paste( new[!is.element( new, old )], collapse = ", " ) )

    common_list = intersect(old, new )
    is_equal_test = new_desc[common_list] == old_desc[common_list]
    if( !all( is_equal_test ) )
      message("modified objects: "
        , paste( common_list[!is_equal_test], collapse = ", " ) )

    options( "old_desc" = new_desc )

    TRUE
  }

  invisible(addTaskCallback(f = eventHandler, name = "my_event_handler"))
}
```

That's it.

```
> .my.callback.fun() # start the callback function
Loading required package: digest
> 
> # your R commands here
> x = 1:10
new objects: x
> y = rnorm(100)
new objects: y
> rm( x )
deleted objects: x
> for (i in 1:10) 
+   z = rep(i, 1000 )
new objects: i, z
> rm( z, y )
deleted objects: y, z
> if( TRUE )
+   h = rnorm(1000)
new objects: h
> h = rnorm(1000)
modified objects: h
> fn = function() assign( "x", rnorm(1000), envir = .GlobalEnv )
new objects: fn
> fn()
new objects: x
> 
> iris = iris
new objects: iris
> iris[5,1] = 0.0
modified objects: iris
> 
> removeTaskCallback(id = "my_event_handler" ) # stop the callback function
[1] TRUE
```

If I drop the 'modify' option and monitor only creations and deletions, it's far simplier and faster.

```
.my.callback.fun <- function() {
  .old <- ls( envir= .GlobalEnv, all.names = TRUE )
  options( "old_ls" = .old )

  eventHandler <- function(...) {
    # list the current .GlobalEnv
    new <- ls( envir= .GlobalEnv, all.names = TRUE )
    old = getOption( "old_ls") # get the previous .GlobalEnv

    if (!all( is.element( old,  new ) ) ) 
      message("deleted objects: ", paste( old[!is.element( old, new )], collapse = ", " ) )

    if (!all( is.element( new, old ) ) )
      message("new objects: ", paste( new[!is.element( new, old )], collapse = ", " ) )

    options( "old_ls" = new )

    TRUE
  }

  invisible(addTaskCallback(f = eventHandler, name = "my_event_handler"))
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Your approach works very well and might be the only way to do this thoroughly. My fear is that it takes too long considering that it gets called for very top-level expression. I will play around a little and see whether I can combine it with the basic expression analysis I used in my example. Any specific reason you used the `sha1` algorithm?

Comment: Yes, after each top level expr, all objects will be send to get.hash which can take long on big objects. No, no particular reason - I used to use it...

Answer (score 3):

So, you *basically want to know if any objects were added or changed in the
global environment and only execute [your] callback if that is the case.*.

Here's a quite simple solution making use of (currently experimental) `base` R function `lockEnvironment`, which prevents any change in a given environment. Unfortunately, there is no `unlock*` counterpart, so we have to execute [this gist](https://gist.github.com/wch/3280369#file-unlockenvironment-r) first.

```
# source *https://gist.github.com/wch/3280369* first


globalChange <- function (expr, envir = parent.frame()) {
   lockEnvironment(.GlobalEnv, TRUE)

   ..change <- FALSE
   tryCatch({
      eval(expr, envir=envir)
   },
   error=function(err) {
      # you may want to check whether err is "cannot add bindings to a locked environment" here
      ..change <<- TRUE
   })

   unlockEnvironment(.GlobalEnv) # see https://gist.github.com/wch/3280369

   # unlock all bindings (unlockEnvironment doesn't do that)
   for (obj in ls(envir=.GlobalEnv, all=TRUE))
      unlockBinding(obj, .GlobalEnv)

   ..change
}
```

This function returns `TRUE` if there was an error while evaluating a given `expr`. It runs with the global environment locked, so you will surely get `TRUE` *if any objects were added or changed in the global environment*.

Some examples:

```
globalChange({
   x <- 100
})
## [1] TRUE
globalChange({
  print("a")
})
## [1] "a"
## [1] FALSE
globalChange({
  f <- function() { x <<- 100 }
  f()
})
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: This looks interesting! I have some problems though. Doesn't your approach rerun the whole expression? That has two implications: (1) when I try to integrate `globalChange` in the `eventHandler` in my question, I create a recursive call that adds the eventHandler 1000+ times. Just replace the if condition with a call to `globalChange`. (2) Long-running expressions that do not make any assignments get executed twice (and assignments maybe only fail after the execution of the function?).

Comment: This wasn't really part of my question but I guess there is no way to detect which binding changed?

Comment: @user2503795: Yes, it needs a "preflighting" eval. An no, there's no insight into which objects have changed (I thought that you want to check whether *any* object has changed).

Comment: As I said, which object changed isn't crucial but I was just curious. Can you be a little more specific about "preflighting" eval?

Comment: @user2503795: If you want to eval f() iff f() doesn't mess up in global env, then you have to eval f() with locked global env (preflight via globalChange), and then if globalChange returns TRUE, then you execute f() once again, this time with globalenv unlocked. This is 2x f() eval.

Comment: This seems like the better solution for the bounty but I am still not sure about the integration with `addTaskCallback`. The callback passed to `addTaskCallback` gets called after each top-level expression. How do I add your `globalChange` function to the callback so that the callback only continues to run when the expression made a change in the global environment? Simply replacing condition in if in my example `eventHandler` doesn't work.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought you'd wish to re-implement the taskCallback mechanism yourself without relying on R's facilities...