# In R, how can we determine whether the result of a function is assigned to a variable or not?

Tags: r, function, variable-assignment

I want my function to bahave differently whether its results are assigned to a variable or not. For instance:

```
my.function <- function(x) {

  (...)

  if(assignment) {
    return(results)
  } else {
    cat("Haha! You're not assigning this result to any variable!
         Do you even know what you're doing??")
    cat(results)
    return()
  }
}
```

I've seen two other questions dealing with that matter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23673582/how-can-i-check-whether-an-expression-was-an-assignment-in-callback-passed-to) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18972845/get-last-top-level-command-as-a-character-string), but I'm hoping there might be a more straightforward way to achieve this. Or maybe there isn't...?

Comment: checking with function `exists` if `results` exists in the function environment ?

Comment: Good try, but no, the results will always exist. It's what I do with them that will change. (Echo them in a specific manner when no assignment is made, and just return them normally when an assignment is made indeed.

Comment: just curious are you afraid that the object is too big to print ?

Comment: It could have been that, but no. It's rather that my function allows the user to pick between several output modes (formatted output to console or to file, or unformated table. And to avoid redundancy and additionnal parameters, knowing where the results end up can actually inform me not to print any thing at all if the assignment is made.

Comment: No, there is no straightforward way. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13058062/1412059

Comment: Hmm nothing encouraging indeed.